# Clear Filter in datagrid

Tags: extjs

Im having trouble with the clear filter.

I have a button called filter_clear and I want to do is that it should remove all the filtered data in my datagrid, here is my code

```
filter_clear:function(button){
console.log("Clear Filter"); 
  var store = grid.getStore();
    // clear any fliters that have been applied
    store.clearFilter( true );
    // load the store
    store.load();
},
```

but its not working, any ideas? thanks in advance :D

Comment: What does "not working" mean? What happens? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: I want to remove the entered string in my filter box and together refresh the grid

Comment: There's really not much we can tell with just this snippet of code without seeing the rest of the app, but have you tried `store.clearFilter()` without the suppress bool and  store.load right after?  Also, have you tried `store.filters.clear(); store.load();`?  And either way, when you clear the filters, are they removed?  Do you see an AJAX call for your data (if the data's remote)?

Comment: I'd tried what you say, It works :D Thanks buddy. But One Problem still remain, how can I clear the one that I typed in the textfield box? the grid clear all the filtered data but the one I type is still in the textfield box.

Comment: @GarfieldBesa: Are you asking how to clear the actual text typed into the textfield or the filter created from the text typed into that textfield?  What I said in my comment should've cleared any filters on the store...